# jQuery, Rails and fullCalendar: How to set DELETE method on url using jQuery or fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, fullcalendar

I have been thinking about for few days on what is possible with fulLCalendar, jQuery on Rails 3.2.8.

I used as_json, url to access records in model/ActiveRecords as shown below:

```
class ZigzagPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :calories_journals

  attr_accessor :no_of_cycles
  attr_accessible :zz_type_used, :normal_mn_ratio_used, :start_date, :no_of_cycles

    # need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
    # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
    def as_json(options = {})
        {
            :id => self.id,
            :title => self.zz_type_used,
            :start => self.start_date.rfc822,
            :end => self.end_date.rfc822,
            :allDay => true,
            :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.zigzag_plan_path(id),  ****
            :color => 'darkGrey',
            textColor: 'white'
        }
    end  
end
```

I am curious whether it is possible to set DELETE method on url as I am trying to develop a delete feature that will not only delete event on a calendar but also deletes the event from the database or activerecords after javascript/coffeescript dialog confirmation box.

```
$(document).ready ->  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar      
    header:
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next today',

    eventSources: [{
      url: '/zigzag_plans'
    },
    {
      url: '/calories_journals'
    }],

    eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) ->
      alert "Deleting!" if confirm "Delete '#{calEvent.title} Journals from: #{calEvent.start} to: #{calEvent.end}' - Are you sure?" if not calEvent.title.match(/(Low|High) Day/)
      removeEvent(calEvent.id) if not calEvent.title.match(/(Low|High) Day/)

removeEvent = (calEvent_id) -> $('#calendar').fullCalendar("removeEvents", calEvent_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send delete request with jquery

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/resource",
    type: "POST",
    data: { _method:'DELETE' },

    success: function(msg) {
        // do something with result
    }
 });
```

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE", url: "/path/to/resource",
    success: function(msg) {
        // do something with result
    }
 }); This works as well.  Thx for suggesting jQuery way.